# Comparing strings seems to be not working properly

Tags: java, string, equals

I'm currently working on my CharRoom project in Java 8. I'm trying to solve a bug, which appears when two clients connect with the same nickname. The simplest and also sufficient solution I've come up is to add " (1)" when a new client has the same nickname as one of the other clients.

```
            for(int i = 0; i < newClientNum; i++) // loop not considering new client 
            {
                System.out.println("Client " + i + " nickname: " + clients[i].nickname);
                if(clients[newClientNum].nickname.equals(clients[i].nickname));
                {
                    clients[newClientNum].nickname += " (1)";
                    System.out.println("New clients new nickname: " + clients[newClientNum].nickname);
                    i = -1;
                }
            }
```

Which seems to be incorrect.
Here is an output when there are two users connected with same nickname "user".

```
Client 0 nickname: user
New clients new nickname: user (1) (1) (1) (1) (1) (1) (1) ... 
Client 0 nickname: user
New clients new nickname: user (1) (1) (1) (1) (1) (1) (1) ... 
...
```

Comment: why do you reset i to -1 ??

Comment: it becomes i=0 in the next iteration so it checks again if there is someone with nickname "user (1)" and change new client's nickname to "user (1) (1)"

Comment: such manipulation of loop index is really BAD programming .....

Comment: so how should I change it?

Comment: @foxale you could go through all of the `clients` up to `newClientNum`, adding their nicknames to a `Set<String>`; then just do `while (!set.add(clients[newClientNum].nickname)) { clients[newClientNum].nickname += " (1)"; }`.

Comment: Works perfectly and looks much smoother, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a trailing `;` at the end of the `if` that doesn't belong there:

> ```
>   if(clients[newClientNum].nickname.equals(clients[i].nickname));
>         {
>             clients[newClientNum].nickname += " (1)";
>             System.out.println("New clients new nickname: " + clients[newClientNum].nickname);
>             i = -1;
>         }
> ```

This is equivalent to this code, which is not what you want:

```
if (clients[newClientNum].nickname.equals(clients[i].nickname)) {
    // do nothing
}

clients[newClientNum].nickname += " (1)";
System.out.println("New clients new nickname: " + clients[newClientNum].nickname);
i = -1;
```

Delete the `;` at the end of the `if` statement.

Comment: ... and another 2 hours spent on a single semicolon missplacement
Thank you!